# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: messages is not iterable

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Messenger.jsx:53 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: messages is not iterable
at handleSubmit (Messenger.jsx:53:1)

In react I am getting an error related to object not iterable and code is

```
export default function Messenger() {

  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.loginUse)

  const [chat,setChat]=useState(null)
  const [newMessage, setNewMessage]=useState("")
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);



  useEffect(() => {
    const getChat = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/message/" + chat?._id);
        setMessages(res.data);
        console.log(res.data)
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    getChat();
  }, [chat]);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const msg = {
      conversationId: chat?._id,
      sender: user?.data._id,
      text: newMessage,
    };

  const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/message/add", msg);
  setMessages([...messages, res.data])
  setNewMessage("");
};



  return (
    <>
      <NavBar />
      <div className="messenger">
        
    <div className="chatBox">
      <div className="chatBoxWrapper">
        {chat ? (<>
            <div className="chatBoxTop">
            {messages && messages.data && messages.data.map((msg) => (
                <div key={msg._id} >
                  <Message message={msg} own={msg.sender === user.data._id} />
                </div>
              ))}
           
            </div>
            
            <div className="chatBoxBottom">
              <textarea
                className="chatMessageInput"
                placeholder="write something..."
                onChange={(e)=> setNewMessage(e.target.value)}
                value={newMessage}
                
               
              ></textarea>
              <button className="chatSubmitButton" onClick={handleSubmit}>
                Send
              </button>
            </div>
         
            </>
            ):(<span className="noConversationText">
            Open a conversation to start a chat.
          </span>
          )}
      </div>
    </div>
  
  </div>
</>
);
```

}

I am getting an error in handleSubmit function when I iterate setMessage.API for posting data is working and I am getting a response in res.data but not iterate successfully and get an error

```
Messenger.jsx:53 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: messages is not iterable
at handleSubmit (Messenger.jsx:53:1)
```

Comment: So, what kind of data did you get? Show the log of `res.data`.